# Managing sharedPointers C++

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

I'm trying to create the relationships shown in the diagram below.
A is creating a B-object as a shared pointer. It then goes on to pass the shared pointer to a bunch of D's.

But when a B is created, it creates a C object, which is to be hidden from A, and only known by B. Though C must know B to work.

Since a shared pointer is already made to B, is there any way to pass that shared pointer to C from within the constructor of B?

Of course I can make it work by passing the `this`-pointer to C, and store it as a raw pointer. But what happens when B is destroyed? Then C would try to delete the B-pointer, but since that is already in the process of deleting, what happens then?

I hope you can sort this out for me.

Best regards.

[image]

Comment: `C` is a member object of `B` right?

Comment: Why would C try to delete B? B's lifetime is managed by the shared_ptrs, not by C.

Comment: @nwp That actually makes sense. When B is deleted when the refCount is 0, it would delete C. C would then not need to delete the pointer, because the object it is pointing on, B, is already deleted?

Comment: Technically B outlives C because B manages the lifetime of C. Which is good because C can always rely on the B pointer to be valid. But yes, once C is destructed B will follow immediately, no reason for C to do anything.

Comment: Your UML diagram doesn't look quite right to me, some of your diamonds are at the [wrong end](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition#UML_notation) I think.

Comment: if C has a shared pointer to B, how could B's ref count reach to 0? When you have a circle relationship, you probably need to use weak pointer

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, then `B` could inherit [`std::enable_shared_from_this`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this), and pass a shared pointer of itself when it's creating the `C` objects. Possibly the `C` object should have a `std::weak_ptr` to its "parent" `B` object instead.

Without weak pointers the lifetime of the `C` objects *must* be fully managed by the `B` object.

---

If on the other hand the `B` object manages the lifetime of the `C` objects, then the `C` objects might not need a shared pointer to the `B` object but instead have a non-owning (plain raw) pointer to the `B` object.

Comment: Correct. As @nwp mentioned, B outlives C hence a normal pointer will be sufficient. Thank you.

Comment: Your solution introduces memory leak.

Comment: @user3188346 Where?

Comment: The member owns a shared_ptr to its owner. Unless you invalidate somehow the shared_ptr in C object, B will never be destroyed.

Comment: @user3188346 If the `B` object manages the lifetime of the `C` objects then it doesn't matter. A `B` object creates a `C` object, and the reference counter for the `B` object is increased. But then the `B` object *deletes* the `C` object and the reference counter is decreased. Once all `C` objects containing a shared pointer to the `B` object have gone, then there would be only the shared pointer in the `A` object left. No leak.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude If you assume that it will be managed manually, what's the point of using shared pointers in this case?

Comment: @user3188346 And that's the point of the second section in the answer.